# postgress connection to server on socket failed

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-14

`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory`
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

`brew uninstall postgresql`

`brew install postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Remove postmaster.pid file

`rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

`brew services restart postgresql`